# Problem with code for Image switching on click using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I recently learnt Jquery and have an issue with figuring out how to write code for switching image on click. I'd appreciate it if someone helps me out with this, below are the code and output for that. **I'm trying to get the output like the ones you see on Flipkart where on left, images are on the column and on the right you get the bigger image of which you clicked on the left**, I know the Jquery part is blunder,but don't know how to proceed next

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".img .1").click(function() {
    $(this).css({
      margin: "500px",
      border: "2px solid black"
    });
  });
  $(".img .2").click(function() {
    $(this).css({
      margin: "500px",
      border: "2px solid black"
    });
  });
  $(".img .3").click(function() {
    $(this).css({
      margin: "500px",
      border: "2px solid black"
    });
  });
  $(".img .4").click(function() {
    $(this).css({
      margin: "500px",
      border: "2px solid black"
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 700px;
  width: 700px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: block;
}

.img {
  width: 75px;
  height: 80px;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.main {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>watch</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
    integrity = "sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
    crossorigin = "anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="slides">
      <img class="img 1" src="images/1.jpg">
      <img class="img 2" src="images/2.jpg">
      <img class="img 3" src="images/3.jpg">
      <img class="img 4" src="images/4.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. You had incorrect script tags and you had TWO sets of jQuery

Answer (score 1):

You had incorrect script tags and you had TWO sets of jQuery

This is all you need to access ALL images

```
$(".img").click(function() {
  $(this).css({
    margin: "500px",
    border: "2px solid black"
  });
});
```

However you cannot see the border effect because they all already have the border

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".img").click(function() {
    $(this).css({
      margin: "500px",
      border: "2px solid black"
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 700px;
  width: 700px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: block;
}

.img {
  width: 75px;
  height: 80px;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px;
}

.main {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>watch</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
    integrity = "sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
    crossorigin = "anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="slides">
      <img class="img" src="images/1.jpg">
      <img class="img" src="images/2.jpg">
      <img class="img" src="images/3.jpg">
      <img class="img" src="images/4.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

But you likely just want to show an image to the right:

Note I changed the border css to a class

```js
$(function() {
  $(".img").on("click", function() {
    $(".img").removeClass("active"); // remove from all 
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $("#big").attr("src", this.src)
  });
  $(".img").eq(0).click(); // initialise
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 700px;
  width: 700px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: flex;
}

.img {
  width: 75px;
  height: 80px;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.main {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.active {
  border: 2px solid black
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>watch</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="slides">
      <img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500?text=Image+1">
      <img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500?text=Image+2">
      <img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500?text=Image+3">
      <img class="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500?text=Image+4">
    </div>
    <div class="main"><img id="big" src=""></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Excuse me, I have accidentally edited your answer instead of mine.

Comment: Thanks and I'm terribly sorry for editing your code.

Comment: My second example seems to be what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

Don't repeat code, remove the border for siblings:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".img").click(function() {
    $(this).css({
      margin: "500px",
      border: "2px solid black"
    });
    $(this).siblings().each(function() {
        $(this).css(border: 'none');
    })
  });
});

.img {
  width: 75px;
  height: 80px;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px;
}
```